# React native navigation newbie: Fullscreen width on a showInAppNotification?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-navigation

I'm using `react-native-navigation` to show error notification dropdowns via 'showInAppNotification'.

I've tried to style the dropdown box with:

```
{
  backgroundColor: colorRed,
  flex: 1,
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
}
```

I can't get the box to obey that `flex` call. It stays as the width of the text inside the notification.

That is, what I get is this:

[image: Bad Notification Width]

And what I want is this:

[image: Good Notification Width]

(The second is achieved by setting a hard width of 999, but that isn't a satisfactory solution)

So, from my limited understanding of React Native's stylesheet logic, I assumed I had a parent element with a fixed width above the notification. Except I don't. It's called directly (well, unless I'm missing some sort of injected showInAppNotification component) into my Provider HOC, which looks like this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <ErrorBoundary>
    {children}
  </ErrorBoundary>
</Provider>
```

To confirm the `ErrorBoundary` was fullscreen width, I threw a `backgroundColor: green` on the error boundary. It came back as the expected width, like this:

[image: Notification Green Background]

Any thoughts on what could be going on? As mentioned I'm new to react native & it's possible I'm missing something obvious w/regards to flex logic, but I suspect it's a react-native-navigator notification issue I'm hoping others have run into. Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving your width a hard-coded value you can import react native's **Dimensions** class into your component and use it in order to set the width.

So, your code can look something like this:

```
import { ...., Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = {
    notification : {
        backgroundColor: colorRed,
        width,
        alignSelf: 'stretch'
    }
}
```